# How do I Routing System.Diagnostics though NLog to ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nlog

I'm using Nlog to write logs to Elasticsearch, which works just fine.
The issue is that I'm now trying to route System.Diagnostics though NLog to Elasticsearch.

I was following the tutorial @ https://nlog-project.org/2010/09/02/routing-system-diagnostics-trace-and-system-diagnostics-tracesource-logs-through-nlog.html

But the phrase "application configuration file" has me confused, I assumed it was app.config ?

The nlog config looks like

```xml
    <configuration>
        <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog Log.xsd"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              autoReload="true"
              internalLogLevel="Info">
            <extensions>
                <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
            </extensions>
            <targets>
                <target name="console"  layout="${longdate} ${windows-identity} ${message}" />
                
                <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" name="elasticsearch"
                       uri="http://elasticsearch.dev.xxx-xxx.cloud/"
                       index="BTR.TestAutomation.Shared.Common"
                       includeAllProperties="True"
                       disableAutomaticProxyDetection="True"
                       requireAuth="True"
                       username="xxx"
                       password="xxx">
                </target>
    
                <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="C:/execution.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}"
                archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/log.{#}.txt"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
                archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMddHHmm"
                maxArchiveFiles="0"
                concurrentWrites="true"
                networkWrites="true"
                />
            </targets>
    
            <rules>
                <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
                <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="elasticsearch" />
                <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
            </rules>
        </nlog>
    </configuration>
```

app.config

is as in the tutorial

```xml
    <configuration>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
          <source name="System.Net" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
              <add name="nlog" />
            </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.Net.Sockets" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
              <add name="nlog" />
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
          <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
        </sharedListeners>
      </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```

The stack trace appears on the console but no logging as of tutorial
using the code.

```cpp
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadString("http://somehost/nosuchfile.txt");
```

I have also tried doing this code.

Having removed the app.config

```cpp
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new NLogTraceListener());
    Trace.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

This gives no output at all.

My preference would be the second method as I allow users to enable and disable when debugging code

Thank you for spending you time on this rather long POST

A.

Comment: Maybe your NLog.config is missing `Copy if newer`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: tnx for the link

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5107

Comment: FYI the Tutorial mentioned is out of date.

Comment: github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5107 was Opened by me after going through  github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Yes attempting to use deprecated Tracing-features with .NET Core will probably not give the expected results. The tutorial works very well with legacy .NET Framework, eventhough tutorial is now 12 years old.